# Bulk upsert with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, upsert

I am working on bulk upserting lots of data into PostgreSQL with SQLAlchemy 1.1.0b, and I'm running into duplicate key errors.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

import pg

engine = create_engine("postgresql+pygresql://" + uname + ":" + passw + "@" + url)

# reflectively load the database.
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(bind=engine)
session = sessionmaker(autocommit=True, autoflush=True)
session.configure(bind=engine)
session = session()
base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

table_name = "arbitrary_table_name" # this will always be arbitrary
mapped_table = getattr(base.classses, table_name)
# col and col2 exist in the table.
chunks = [[{"col":"val"},{"col2":"val2"}],[{"col":"val"},{"col2":"val3"}]]

for chunk in chunks:
    session.bulk_insert_mappings(mapped_table, chunk)
    session.commit()
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pg.IntegrityError) ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint <constraint>
```

I can't seem to properly instantiate the `mapped_table` as a `Table()` object, either.

I'm working with time series data, so I'm grabbing data in bulk with some overlap in time ranges. I want to do a bulk upsert to ensure data consistency.

What's the best way to do a bulk upsert with a large data set? I know [PostgreSQL support upserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql) now, but I'm not sure how to do this in SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26018934/465974

> After I found this command, I was able to perform upserts, but it is
>   worth mentioning that this operation is slow for a bulk "upsert".
>
> The alternative is to get a list of the primary keys you would like to
>   upsert, and query the database for any matching ids:

Comment: Please flag the question as a duplicate instead of copying the answer

Comment: Marking as correct since this problem is long solved. :)