# Bulk Upsert with SQLAlchemy Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, upsert

I'm following the SQLAlchemy documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html) to write a bulk upsert statement with Postgres. For demonstration purposes, I have a simple table `MyTable`:

```py
class MyTable(base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    id = Column(types.Integer, primary_key=True)
    test_value = Column(types.Text)
```

Creating a generic insert statement is simple enough:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

values = [{'id': 0, 'test_value': 'a'}, {'id': 1, 'test_value': 'b'}]
insert_stmt = postgresql.insert(MyTable.__table__).values(values)
```

The problem I run into is when I try to add the "on conflict" part of the upsert.

```py
update_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
    index_elements=[MyTable.id],
    set_=dict(data=values)
)
```

Trying to execute this statement yields a `ProgrammingError`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgres://localhost/db_name')

engine.execute(update_stmt)

>>> ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'dict'
```

I think my misunderstanding is in constructing the statement with the `on_conflict_do_update` method. Does anyone know how to construct this statement? I have looked at other questions on StackOverflow (eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579049/bulk-upsert-with-sqlalchemy)) but I can't seem to a way to address the above error.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
update_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
    index_elements=[MyTable.id],
    set_=dict(data=values)
)
```

index_elements should either be a list of strings or a list of column objects. So either `[MyTable.id]` or `['id']` (This is correct)

set_ should be a dictionary with column names as keys and valid sql update objects as values. You can reference values from the insert block using the `excluded` attribute. So to get the result you are hoping for here you would want `set_={'test_value': insert_stmt.excluded.test_value}` (The error you made is that `data=` in the example isn't a magic argument... it was the name of the column on their example table)

So, the whole thing would be

```
update_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
    index_elements=[MyTable.id],
    set_={'test_value': insert_stmt.excluded.test_value}
)
```

Of course, in a real world example I usually want to change more then one column. In that case I would do something like...

```
update_columns = {col.name: col for col in insert_stmt.excluded if col.name not in ('id', 'datetime_created')}
update_statement = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(index_elements=['id'], set_=update_columns)
```

(This example would overwrite every column except for the id and datetime_created columns)

Comment: Great answer - super clear and easy to follow. Thanks!

Comment: This optimised my horrendous alpha code from 90 seconds to 9 seconds. Someone once told me "never execute SQL statements in a loop" and it stuck with me. I knew I had to find a better way, so - cheers!

Comment: I keep getting `AttributeError: 'Insert' object has no attribute 'excluded'` when i'm trying to compose the update_columns. My insert statement looks like this: `insert_statement = insert(table).values(items)` where table is of type DeclarativeMeta and items is a list of dicts. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: i figured it out... for anyone with this problem, pay big attention to where you import the insert from. it should be `from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert` not `from sqlalchemy import insert`. god.

Comment: Yes, for database specific constructs like this, you have to import from the dialect directly.

Comment: clear and easy. tks