# SQLAlchemy: Insert or Update when column value is a duplicate

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table `A` with the following columns:

- id `UUID`
- str_identifier `TEXT`
- num `FLOAT`

and a table `B` with similar columns:

- str_identifier `TEXT`
- num `FLOAT`
- entry_date `TIMESTAMP`

I want to construct a sqlalchemy query that does the following:

- finds entries in table `B` that either do not exist yet in table `A`, and inserts them
- finds entries in table `B` that *do* exist in table `A` but have a different value for the `num` column

The catch is that table `B` has the `entry_date` column, and as a result can have multiple entries with the same `str_identifier` but different entry dates. So I always want to perform this insert/update query using the latest entry for a given `str_identifier` (if it has multiple entries in table `B`).

For example, if before the query runs tables `A` and `B` are:

```
[A]
|  id | str_identifier  |  num  |
|-----|-----------------|-------|
| 1   | str_id_1        |   25  |


[B]
| str_identifier | num | entry_date |
|----------------|-----|------------|
| str_id_1       | 89  | 2020-07-20 |
| str_id_1       | 25  | 2020-06-20 |
| str_id_1       | 50  | 2020-05-20 |
| str_id_2       | 45  | 2020-05-20 |
```

After the update query, table `A` should look like:

```
[A]
|  id | str_identifier  | num |
|-----|-----------------|-----|
|  1  | str_id_1        | 89  |
|  2  | str_id_2        | 45  |
```

The query I've constructed so far should detect difference, but will adding `order_by(B.entry_date.desc())` ensure I only do the `exist` comparisons with the latest `str_identifier` values?

My Current Query

```
query = (
        select([B.str_identifier, B.value])
        .select_from(
            join(B, A, onclause=B.str_identifier == A.str_identifier, isouter=True)
        )
        .where(
            and_(
                ~exists().where(
                    and_(
                        B.str_identifier == A.str_identifier,
                        B.value == A.value,
                        ~B.value.in_([None]),
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Hi Megan. You have described your requirements quite well, but you haven't given any indication of the research you have done or the things you may have tried. Your question in its current form may well attract downvotes because "Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service". What you describe is known as an "upsert". Please research that and then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you for the response. I'm not super well-versed with `sqlalchemy` and didn't want to post my obviously wrong attempts, but I can add those in.

Comment: You may be interested in examples of upserts for [PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61366664/2144390) and [SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62388767/2144390).

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you, I'll take a look.