# Inserting new record which was already existing in PostgreSql

Tags: python, sql

How can I insert new record which is already existing in SQL.

I have a table in database. It has 3 columns (numbers, first_name, last_name).
"numbers" column's row starts from 1 to 500.
Now, I'm importing .csv file to database. Those new file's informations "numbers" column starts from 1 to 600.

When I import them, it needs to continue from 501 where old rows were stopped at.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing csv file to Database using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70302207/importing-csv-file-to-database-using-python)

Comment: Please update your initial question if you need to add details instead of asking a new one.